Last scene: A woman in apocalypse
It's been a lot of years, I am not able to find the name of the movie because the details I remember are very little and it's only about the last scene.
Let me describe the last scene as much as I remember (the details are messed up and not in sequential order), there's a woman (I guess, one of the starring characters) left alone in the apocalyptic world. I believe the apocalyptic world is about cyberpunk and war. The woman seemed to be a fighter and had a advanced shotgun. There was also a glimpse of newspaper lying in trash/ground. The camera moves away from her (she's also walking towards somewhere, I could see some perfectly crafted holes on her body or maybe some equipment near her) and starts showing the world, the credits starts scrolling and movie ends.
I know the details are very less and speculative but if anybody who remembers the movie well will be able to hit the movie name immediately. I just had to post that question because that movie's last scene is just not fading away from my memories.

This sounds like the ending of the first "Resident Evil" movie.




Bingo! This scene indeed matches the scene I have in my memories in many ways.
